# Show button only when there is a value in button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a button like this:

```
  <button> {{ pages.first }}</button>

 <button>{{ pages.last }}</button>
```

Sometimes the value {{ pages.first }} can be empty sometimes can't. If the value is empty I don't want to show button at all. I have tried this but this hide button always:

```
if(!$('button').val()){
    $('button').hide();
}
else {
    $('button').show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My button looks like this in the code:

```
<button class="next_prev" onclick="" disabled>{% get_pages %} {{ pages.next }}</button> <button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="last_button" disabled>{% get_pages %} {{ pages.last }}</button>
```

Comment: I think you want `text` here not `val`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `text()` and not `val()`.. and incaseof multiple button you need to loop through the buttons...

try this

```
 $.each($("button"),function(){  //in case of multiple button
  if(!$(this).text()){
    $(this).hide();
   }
  else {
    $(this).show();
  }
})
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/bqb9n/)

Comment: Working with only one button :(

Comment: you can try adding buttons in the fiddle .. it will work even if there is 100 buttons... can u show me your button's htmL??

Comment: make sure the other button is empty... i guessthere is some text in the buttons for it to not get hide.. may be this is the culprit ..`{% get_pages %}`.. check it out and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` to traverse and check all buttons: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/M4tCH/1/)

```
$.each($("button"),function(){
  if(!$(this).text().trim()){
     $('this).hide();
  }
  else {
     $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Your code `.val()` will work for `<input type="submit"/>` buttons

Answer (score 1):

Using `text` instead of `val` will do the trick

```
if(!$('button').text()){
   $('button').hide();
}
else {
  $('button').show();
}
```

Comment: Not working still my whole button looks like this:
<button class="next_prev" onclick="" disabled>{% get_pages %} {{ pages.next }}</button>
              
             <button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="last_button" disabled>{% get_pages %} {{ pages.last }}</button>
I am getting the button even if it's empty.